# android: when i connect my listview to database i lost the styling

Tags: android, listview

when i connect my listview to database i lost the listview style.

and when i add the style i see same data on all of the listview.

```
public void update_list(String NN) {
        //HashMap<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();

       db_results = new ArrayList<String>();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(NN, null);
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            //item.put( "line1",String.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("A"))));
              //item.put( "line2",String.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("B"))));
              //item.put( "line3",String.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("C"))));
              //list.add( item );
             db_results.add(String.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("A"))) + "\n" +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("B")) + "\n" +cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("C")));
         }
        cursor.close();
               setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,db_results));
```

option1: like this code i see the data on my list but i lost the styling.

option2: i un remark the remarked code and i see the styling but same data on all of the list

Answer (score 0):

You'd be much better off to create a custom layout and use a SimpleCursorAdapter to populate it.

**threelinelayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListItem1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ListItem3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**adapter code**

```
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(NN, null); 
this.startManagingCursor(cursor);

String[] from = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ListItem1, R.id.ListItem2, R.id.ListItem3 };
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.threelinelayout, mCursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: thanks for the help !!!  where to put this code (the adapter code) Is this instead of or in addition ?

Comment: You would use it in your `update_list` method in place of what you have there now.  If this works out for you, please click the check mark to accept the answer.

Comment: I did exactly what you type, but got error on:
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.threelinelayout, mCursor, from, to);

Comment: Did you do the import for the SimpleCursorAdapter? You might also try replacing `this` with `getActivity()`  I'll update my answer to reflect that.